# React JS sort by ascending and descending

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I've been using `sortBy` from `lodash`, but keep getting

```
./src/components/Product.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (17:29)

  15 |       sortByPrice() {
  16 |         this.setState(prevState => ({
> 17 |           sortBy(prevState, ['price'])
     |                              ^
  18 |         }));
  19 |       }
  20 |
```

This is my component, in which I want to sort the array of objects based on their price. `this.state` inside `return()` gives me an array, so that seems to be working, I just need to get the `sortByPrice()` working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sortBy from 'lodash/sortBy'
import './Product.css'
import products from '../offers.json'


class Product extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { products }
    this.sortByPrice = this.sortByPrice.bind(this);
  }

  sortByPrice() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      sortBy(prevState, ['price'])
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Product">
      <a href="#" onClick={this.sortByPrice}>
      Click me
      </a>
      <br />
      { products.map((product, index) =>
        <div key ={index} className="card">
        <img src={ product.product.details.image } alt={ product.product.details.ean }/>
        <h3>Prijs: { product.price } Euro</h3>
        <p>Staat: { product.description }</p>
        <p>Verkoper: { product.user.details.firstname }</p>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Product
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out I was trying to call `sortBy()` on and object, which resulted in the error. Implemented this and the errors went away, now I just need to figure out a way to manage my state and re-render the view

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    { products: sortBy(prevState.products, ['price']) }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

After talking to some friends I was advised to ditch `lodash` for this altogether. I just wrote the functions myself, added my binds to the constructor and called my functions in the `onClick` of my ASC and DESC buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Product.css'
import products from '../offers.json'

class Product extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { products }
    this.sortByPriceAsc = this.sortByPriceAsc.bind(this);
    this.sortByPriceDesc = this.sortByPriceDesc.bind(this);
  }

  sortByPriceAsc() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      this.state.products.sort((a, b) => (a.price - b.price))
  });
  }

  sortByPriceDesc() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      this.state.products.sort((a, b) => (b.price - a.price))
  });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      Sorteren:
        <button onClick={this.sortByPriceAsc}>
          ASC
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.sortByPriceDesc}>
          DESC
        </button>
      <div className="product">
      { this.state.products.map((product, index) =>
        <div key ={index} className="card">
          <img src={ product.product.details.image } alt={ product.product.details.ean }/>
          <h3>Prijs: { product.price } Euro</h3>
          <p>Staat: { product.description }</p>
          <p>Verkoper: { product.user.details.firstname }</p>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Product
```

Comment: sort takes an array -> youre giving it an object with an array in it...

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 8):

WORKING CODE:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import './Product.css'
    import products from '../offers.json'

    class Product extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { products }
        this.sortByPriceAsc = this.sortByPriceAsc.bind(this);
        this.sortByPriceDesc = this.sortByPriceDesc.bind(this);
      }

      sortByPriceAsc() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          this.state.products.sort((a, b) => (a.price - b.price))
      });
      }

      sortByPriceDesc() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          this.state.products.sort((a, b) => (b.price - a.price))
      });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
          Sorteren:
            <button onClick={this.sortByPriceAsc}>
            Aflopend
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.sortByPriceDesc}>
            Oplopend
            </button>
          <div className="Product">
          { this.state.products.map((product, index) =>
            <div key ={index} className="card">
              <img src={ product.product.details.image } alt={ product.product.details.ean }/>
              <h3>Prijs: { product.price } Euro</h3>
              <p>Staat: { product.description }</p>
              <p>Verkoper: { product.user.details.firstname }</p>
            </div>
          )}
          </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default Product
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sorting an array in ascending and descending order of price-**

```
      sortByPriceAsc=()=>{

          let sortedProductsAsc;
          sortedProductsAsc= this.state.products.sort((a,b)=>{
             return parseInt(a.price)  - parseInt(b.price);
          })

          this.setState({
              products:sortedProductsAsc
          })
      }


      sortByPriceDsc=()=>{

          let sortedProductsDsc;
          sortedProductsDsc= this.state.products.sort((a,b)=>{
             return parseInt(b.price)  - parseInt(a.price);
          })

          this.setState({
              products:sortedProductsDsc
          })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  return sortBy(prevState, ['price'])
});
```

(Drop the extra parentheses around the block, and I think you need a `return`?)

**UPDATE**

I think you can drop the return if you drop the curly braces:

```
this.setState(prevState => sortBy(prevState, ['price']));
```

**UPDATE 2**

As a commenter above pointed out, you also need to pass the actual array. My answer will presumably get you to running code, but it still won't do what you want until you sort the right member of the state object.

**UPDATE 3**

Putting it all together, I believe this should resolve the syntax error and actually do the sorting you want to do:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    { products: sortBy(prevState.products, ['price']) }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This got rid of the error, but it isn't re-rendering my view.

Answer (score 0):

So here we sort the **DATA** in ascending or descending order as we click on the button or icon. I'm using React Hooks here.

- sort() method in JavaScript sorts the elements of an array
- **sort()** ***overwrites the original array.***
- Syntax: ***array.sort(compareFunction)***
- When the sort() method compares two values, it sends the values to the compare function, and sorts the   values according to the returned (negative, zero, positive) value.

**Example:**

When comparing 20 and 100, the sort() method calls the compare function(20,100). The function calculates 20-100, and returns -80 (a negative value). The sort function will sort 20 as a value lower than 100.

So, here in **handleSort()** function we are creating new array from the **DATA** so that react can update the state if we use the same array so react thinks nothing change we are just pointing the same array so that's why we need to update the state with new array so that react knows state is changed and it will re-render the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [MyArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
  const [sortStatus, setSortStatus] = useState(true);

  const handleSort = () => {
    const data = MyArray;
    if (sortStatus) {
        let sorted = data.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
        setMyArray(sorted);
        setSortStatus(!sortStatus);
    } else {
        let sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
        setMyArray(sorted);
        setSortStatus(!sortStatus);
    }
  }

 return (
   <>
     <button onClick={handleSort}>ClickMe to Sort</button>
          {/* SHOW YOUR ARRAY here TO SEE THE CHANGES ONCLICK */}
   </>
   )
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.